# Could someone please explain me this function that returns x in power n?

Tags: javascript, function

I am completely new to javascript and just started learning it.
While studying loops and functions with parameters I came across this function meant to multiply x by itself n times and return the result.
Could you explain the function to me?
I really don't get at which point x interacts with n.
Thank you very much.

```
function pow(x, n) {
  let result = x;

  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    result *= x;
  }

  return result;
}

let x = prompt("x?", '');
let n = prompt("n?", '');

if (n < 1) {
  alert(`Power ${n} is not supported,
    use an integer greater than 0`);
} else {
  alert( pow(x, n) );
}
```

Comment: The loop is a counting loop from `1` to `n - 1`, so it runs the statement inside it `n - 1` times. The statement inside it is equivalent to `result = result * x;`, so the loop means multiply `result` by `x`, `n - 1` times. Since `result` is initialized to `x` the final `result` is `x*x**(n-1) === x**n`.

Comment: FYI, if the first line was changed to `let result = 1;` and the loop was changed to run `n` times instead of `n - 1` (E.G. `for ( let i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {`. It would give the same result, but would also work for `n === 0`. The loop would mean: "multiply `result` by `x`, `n` times, and since result is initialized to `1`, the result is equal to `1*x**n === x**n`.

Comment: Hey, best not to downvote spam everyone trying to help you...

Comment: @BrandonDyer She cannot downvote

Comment: @BrandonDyer I downvoted your answer for saying the statement runs `n` times.  Small inaccuracies like that are extremely confusing for beginners. Don't take it personally; I downvoted your post, not you. Edit your post and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: How are you running the JavaScript? Keep in mind, that you could debug it within the dev tools of your browser (e.g. crome or firefox). That way you can go step by step go through the code and see what it is doing at each line and how it jumps around. Going through it that way will greatly help how the code works. See this for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=30&v=H0XScE08hy8

Answer (score 0):

The loop:

```
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    result *= x;
  }
```

gets executed n times, multiplying x by itself n times

(n-1 times but I'm guessing that is unintended)

Edit: as @Paulpro pointed out: it runs n - 1 times in order to give a correct answer. If it ran n times the result would be `x*x**n === x**(n+1)`

Comment: It runs `n - 1` times in order to give a correct answer. If it ran `n` times the result would be `x*x**n === x**(n+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

this function takes `x` to the power of `n`. Basically the x is multiplied by itself n times.

```
  function pow(x, n) {
      let result = x; // you assing result to be x 

      for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {// you run the loop n cn be one each time the loop is executed i will be incramented until it equals to n 
        result *= x; // this is an expresion basically it is result = result * x here is an example x = 2; so the result will be result =2*2 next time i is incremented result will become 4 at that point the result will be equal to result=4*2 
      }

      return result; // you return the result where you call it 
    }

    let x = prompt("x?", '');
    let n = prompt("n?", '');

    if (n < 1) {
      alert(`Power ${n} is not supported,
        use an integer greater than 0`);
    } else {
      alert( pow(x, n) );
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

`x` interacts with `n` in the `for` loop.

You can see in this loop:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  result *= x;
}
```

This line gets run `n` times:

```js
result *= x;
```

So, we're multiplying the `result` by `x` `n` number of times

Comment: That line is run `n - 1` times, not `n` times.